# Fillna Pandas NaN with mean and median

Tags: python, pandas

I'm starting with python and data science, I have a .csv file with more than 5000 lines.
I want to replace Exerience NaN values with mean for Data scientist and median for data engineer. How can I group this and use fillna.
[image]

Each time I try to use fillna with mean() I have this error :

> TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str NaN

Comment: Could you please post a sample dataset? It's useful for us to help you

Comment: try `df.dtypes` looks like 1,5 is 1 comma 5, should it be 1.5 ? if so you might need to replace the string chars `df['Experience'].str.replace(',','.')` then call `pd.to_numeric(df['Experience'])`

Comment: You probably want to read csv with the option `decimal=','`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you have this table loaded in Pandas in a variable named `df`.
Also assuming that when you say `mean` and `median` you mean of the `Experience` column.

```py
df.loc[
    (df["Metier"] == "Data scientist") & (df["Experience"].isnull()), "Experience"
] = df["Experience"].mean()

df.loc[
    (df["Metier"] == "Data engineer") & (df["Experience"].isnull()), "Experience"
] = df["Experience"].median()
```

Comment: I get this error : TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Comment: See @Quang Hoang 's comment to fix that. The values in `Experience` are strings when they should be floats.

Comment: If you want the median / mean for only the entries where Metier is Data Scientist for example then you need to ammend as following: 
`df.loc[
    (df["Metier"] == "Data scientist") & (df["Experience"].isnull()), "Experience"] = df.loc[df["Metier"] == "Data scientist"]["Experience"].mean()`