# pandas DataFrame: replace nan values with median of columns for each period

Tags: pandas, panel, nan

I've got a pandas DataFrame (panel data) filled mostly with real numbers, but there is a few nan values in it as well.

How can I replace the NaNs with the median of the columns for each year (cross-sectional medians per year)?

| id | year | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2000 | 3.539.101 | 265.152 | .0683649 |
| 1 | 2001 | 3.539.101 | 2.485.833 | NaN |
| 1 | 2002 | NaN | 2.939.903 | NaN |
| 1 | 2003 | 3.733.545 | 3.021.591 | -.0257413 |
| 2 | 2000 | 3.960.184 | NaN | .9781774 |
| 2 | 2001 | 3.960.184 | 9.418.228 | .4855057 |
| 2 | 2002 | 3.960.184 | 9.880.249 | .049056 |
| 2 | 2003 | 3.960.184 | NaN | .2310434 |
| 3 | 2000 | NaN | 1.287.206 | -.0373083 |
| 3 | 2001 | NaN | 1.582.817 | .1202868 |
| 3 | 2002 | 4.724.285 | 1.279.348 | -.1824576 |
| 3 | 2003 | 4.724.285 | 1.213.678 | -.0513311 |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fillna Pandas NaN with mean and median](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59178138/fillna-pandas-nan-with-mean-and-median)

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `df.fillna(df.median())`

Comment: ```df['column'] = df.groupby(['category'])['column'].apply(lambda x:x.fillna(x.median()))``` This is the basic format if you want to impute median grouped by a category.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).